# Cannot see my rewarded Ads on website using Google Ad Manager

Tags: web-development, advertising, google-ads, google-ad-manager

I have set up my site to display rewarded videos - this is a test page where you can check it https://smartle-test.web.app/
It works with the Google provided example Ad unit ID but not with mine.
Can anyone help to understand what I am missing and why my Ad is not loading?

My Ad unit setup:
[image: Ad unit]

---

My line item setup:
[image: Size]

---

[image: Inventory]

---

[image: Creative]

I was recommended to change the Inventory type to "rewarded ad" but I don't have such an option.